# how to get the json string in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i got my json string inside the ajax as function like this way

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/./Service/GetPageInfo",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({

            filename: filename
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

here i get data like

```
[{"main":{"sub":[],"tittle":"manu","startvalue":"","stopvalue":"","status":"","accumalated":"","comment":""}}]
```

i want it in a variable like

```
var  myjsonobject =[{"main":{"sub":[],"tittle":"manu","startvalue":"","stopvalue":"","status":"","accumalated":"","comment":""}}]
```

Comment: did you try `myjsonobject = data` ?

Comment: var myjsonobject = JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: @Loading.. i try this code but i get like this way 

"{
  "GetPageInfoResult": "[{\"main\":{\"sub\":[],\"tittle\":\"hllo\",\"startvalue\":\"\",\"stopvalue\":\"\",\"status\":\"\",\"accumalated\":\"\",\"comment":""}}]
}"

Comment: i actual requerment is after change it into variable i need give like $("tr[id=1] > td:nth-child(1)").text(jmyjsonobject [0].main['tittle']);

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/./Service/GetPageInfo",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({

        filename: filename
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
        var jsonobject = data;

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Also I strongly advise you to use promises to make API calls: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jsonobject= null;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/./Service/GetPageInfo",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({

            filename: filename
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            jsonobject=data;
            alert('Success');

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

If you want wait for ajax response and fill up variable then pass `async: false` in ajax request options.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you need to parse the JSON in your success handler,

```
success: function (data) {
   alert('Success');
   var myjsonobject = JSON.parse( data );
},
```

Comment: it get as myjsonobject is undefined

Comment: @lekshminair where are you checking this value? Outside ajax call this value is undefined because it is populated asynchronously.